# Quels sont les équivalents du « saving throw » et de « (to) save vs. » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, jeux

On a le concept de [*saving throw*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saving_throw#English) dans le jeu de rôle, l'« effort to ward off a specific threat by rolling a die or dice and coming up with a particular number » (Wiktionary), essentiellement une tentative de repousser/(résister à) une menace en obtenant un certain résultat avec un dé, qui se concrétise pour ainsi dire dans l'emploi *(to) [save vs.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/save_vs.#English)* (« against » quelque chose : « to successfully guard against a particular danger », Wiktionary) du genre « Did you manage to save vs. poison? » (« As-tu réussi à [[save](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/save)] contre le poison ? »).

Dans le lexique du jeu de rôle, à quoi réfère-t-on en français pour « saving throw » et quel verbe emploie-t-on dans le contexte d'une phrase comme « Did you manage to save vs. poison? » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

à priori je dirais

> jet de sauvegarde

Par exemple 1d100 sous sa constitution pour résister à un poison.

Si le poison est plus faible le DM peut demander

> fait un jet de sauvegarde : d100 sous 2x ta constitution.

On peut aussi le décliner avec la dextérité, la force, .. selon les circonstances.

Comment: Merci, j'aimerais bien un extrait d'un truc, t'as pas une version française d'un _Players Handbook_ de AD&D ou peu importe, un manuel d'un autre univers, voire un passage d'un scénario officiel ou de quoi de même ?

Comment: J'ai bien peur qu'à l'époque où je JDRisais, il fallait se contenter de la version anglaise, et quand les versions françaises sont arrivées le JDRisais plus :(

Comment: Je comprends parfaitement, une situation qui est aussi un peu la mienne. Il reste toujours le [solo](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18612) ! Je vais peut-être un moment donné ramasser un PH en français et venir mettre qqc ici. Remarque j'ai confiance en ton propos par ailleurs.